# Use javascript with multiple selects to update innerhtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm very new to JavaScript, but trying to learn as I go.  So my question is regarding multiple dynamically generated `<select>`s in a form, and using them to update their corresponding `div>span` content with prices.  I've tried running this a few ways, but I don't understand the errors produced well enough to know how to fix it.
Basically I'm listing domain purchase prices, and the user determines what the domain name is.  In the example below I'm hard coding the domain names, but in my script these would be produced by the PHP session info.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lzq3vcb8/

```js
function getPrice(domain) {
  var getdom = domain + "_prices";
  var putdom = domain + "_displayprice";
  var inner = document.getElementById(getdom).value;
  document.getElementById(putdom).innerHTML = inner;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <select class="form-control" onchange="getPrice('websiteone.info')" id="websiteone.info_prices">
      <option data-price="11.29" value="1">1 Year</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="2">2 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="3">3 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="4">4 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="5">5 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="6">6 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="7">7 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="8">8 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="9">9 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="10">10 Years</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <select class="form-control" onchange="getPrice('websitetwo.info')" id="websitetwo.info_prices">
      <option data-price="11.29" value="1">1 Year</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="2">2 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="3">3 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="4">4 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="5">5 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="6">6 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="7">7 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="8">8 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="9">9 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="10">10 Years</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 alert alert-warning"><span id="websiteone_displayprice">test1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 alert alert-warning"><span id="websitetwo_displayprice">test2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you call the function from `onchange` you pass the string `'websiteone.info'`, then the function appends `'_displayprice'` to get an id of `'websiteone.info_displayprice'` - but you have no element with that id.

Comment: Please check the answer I provided so that you can review your code of what you've missed on your code :)

Comment: Thanks Allan, that did it

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're output elements doesn't match the elements you target on your javascript, please check the code below. use **websiteone.info_displayprice** instead of **websiteone_displayprice** since the domain has **.info** and it will be prepended on display price.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 alert alert-warning"><span id="websiteone.info_displayprice">test1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 alert alert-warning"><span id="websitetwo.info_displayprice">test2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
function getPrice(domain) {
  var getdom = domain + "_prices";
  var putdom = domain + "_displayprice";
  var inner = document.getElementById(getdom).value;
  document.getElementById(putdom).innerHTML = inner;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <select class="form-control" onchange="getPrice('websiteone.info')" id="websiteone.info_prices">
      <option data-price="11.29" value="1">1 Year</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="2">2 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="3">3 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="4">4 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="5">5 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="6">6 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="7">7 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="8">8 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="9">9 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="10">10 Years</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <select class="form-control" onchange="getPrice('websitetwo.info')" id="websitetwo.info_prices">
      <option data-price="11.29" value="1">1 Year</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="2">2 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="3">3 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="4">4 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="5">5 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="6">6 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="7">7 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="8">8 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="9">9 Years</option>
      <option data-price="11.29" value="10">10 Years</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 alert alert-warning"><span id="websiteone.info_displayprice">test1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 alert alert-warning"><span id="websitetwo.info_displayprice">test2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd consider a jQuery solution [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzq3vcb8/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <select class="form-control webprice" myUrl="website_one" id="websiteone_select">
        <option data-price="11.29" value="1">1 Year</option>
        <option data-price="11.29" value="2">2 Years</option>
        <option data-price="11.29" value="3">3 Years</option>
        <option data-price="11.29" value="4">4 Years</option>
        <option data-price="11.29" value="5">5 Years</option>
        <option data-price="11.29" value="6">6 Years</option>
        <option data-price="11.29" value="7">7 Years</option>
        <option data-price="11.29" value="8">8 Years</option>
        <option data-price="11.29" value="9">9 Years</option>
        <option data-price="11.29" value="10">10 Years</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <select class="form-control webprice" myUrl="website_two" id="websitetwo_select">
        <option data-price="11.29" value="1">1 Year</option>
        <option data-price="11.29" value="2">2 Years</option>
        <option data-price="11.29" value="3">3 Years</option>
        <option data-price="11.29" value="4">4 Years</option>
        <option data-price="11.29" value="5">5 Years</option>
        <option data-price="11.29" value="6">6 Years</option>
        <option data-price="11.29" value="7">7 Years</option>
        <option data-price="11.29" value="8">8 Years</option>
        <option data-price="11.29" value="9">9 Years</option>
        <option data-price="11.29" value="10">10 Years</option>
   </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6 alert alert-warning"><span id="display_price">test1</span></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("change", ".webprice", function(){

    // get all of the data we need to make calculations
    yearPrice = Number($('option:selected', this).attr("data-price"));
    years = Number($(this).val());
    finalPrice = Math.floor(yearPrice * years * 100)/100;
    url = $(this).attr("myUrl");

    // display the final price
    displayPrices = "The price for " + url + " over " + years + " years is $" + finalPrice;
    $("#display_price").html(displayPrices);

});
```

Comment: I'm sure your method works great for someone who's very familiar with both JavaScript and jQuery, but I'm just learning JavaScript.  What you're suggesting is that I start learning a extra library before I know what I'm really doing.